# Search within a string for a specific value

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to search within a string for a specific value.

What I want to do is SPLIT the string and look at each value.
If the mySearch.EQUALS(split-string-value) then return the record(s) in a ToList().

This is my code.. It returns ZERO RECORDS

```
// user search for sku = "2012"
// p.productMatch in DB = "2012,2012L,2012LR,2011"

var result = ctx.Products
 .Where(p => p.clientID == Config.ClientID)
 .Where(p => p.productMatch.Contains(sku))
 .Select(v => new ProductView
     {
         productID = v.productID,
         productMatch = v.productMatch,
         productSKU = v.productSKU
     }).ToList();


var results = from w in result
          where w.productMatch.Split(',').Equals(sku)
          select w;


return results.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, in your `where w.productMatch.Split(',').Equals(sku)` line you compare result of `Split()` (which is *array of strings*) with single string `sku`. For obvious reasons this fails. Simply change it to:

```
where w.productMatch.Split(',').Contains(sku)
```

Comment: You can also drop the `ToList()` in the first query.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you’re performing an equality comparison on the `string[]` array produced by the `Split` operation and the `sku` variable. Since the two are of different types, the equality comparison will never succeed.

What you actually need to do is compare *each element* of your `string[]` arrays with `sku`:

```
var results = 
    from w in result
    from part in w.productMatch.Split(',')
    where part.Equals(sku)
    select part;
```

If you want to return the entire record, use:

```
var results = 
    from w in result
    where w.productMatch.Split(',').Any(part => part.Equals(sku))
    select w;
```

Or, better yet, use the `Contains` method, as suggested by @jimmy_keen, for more concise code.